# Update Plot with Date Range Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, date-range

I'm trying to set up a a date range filter that will update my graphs, but no matter what I try, I seem to get errors.  Basically, I'd like to be able to set the date range so that people can look at changes between specific elections.

I'm using data from the Nevada Secretary of State's wesbite for voter registration. I've scraped the data and I have it in a CSV, which I'd be happy to attach here if I could figure out how to do that.
https://www.nvsos.gov/sos/elections/voters/voter-registration-statistics.

Normally I'd break down my code a bit, but I've included all of it in case I made an error somewhere else that I'm not seeing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(plotly)

#### Load Data-----------------------------------------------------------------
nv_data <- read_csv("Data/NV_Data_Clean.csv")    

nv_data <- nv_data %>%
      mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date), 
             Party = factor(Party, levels = c("Total", "Democrat", "Republican",
                                              "Nonpartisan", "Other")))%>%
      mutate(District = factor(District))
    
    
    ### separate out data by the district types ------------------------------------
    
    
    county <- nv_data %>%
      filter(`District Type` == "County")
    
    assembly <- nv_data %>%
      filter(`District Type` == "Assembly")
    
    senate <- nv_data %>%
      filter(`District Type` == "Senate")
    
    ageparty <- nv_data %>%
      filter(`District Type` == "Age and Party") 
    
    
    
    ### Create function for the date range -----------------------------------------
    
    monthStart <- function(x) {
      x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
      x$mday <- 1
      as.Date(x)
    }
    
    ###  build the components of the UI --------------------------------------------
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        #menuItem(text = "Home", tabName = "home"),
        menuItem(text = "Counties", tabName = "countiesdistricts"),
        menuItem(text = "Senate Districts", tabName = "senatedistricts"),
        menuItem(text = "Assembly Districts", tabName = "assemblydistricts"),
        menuItem(text = "Age and Party", tabName = "agegroups")
      )
    )
    
    body <- dashboardBody(
      mainPanel(
        tabItems(
          tabItem("countiesdistricts",
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(selectInput("county_districtname", "Select County",
                                         unique(county$District)),
                             dateRangeInput("county_dateRange", "Select Date Ragne: ",
                                            format = "mm/yyyy",
                                            start = min(county$Date),
                                            end = max(county$Date),
                                            startview = "year",
                                            separator = " - "),
                             # textOutput("countyDates"),
                             # more stuff here
                             plotly::plotlyOutput("countyplot")
                    ))
          ),
          tabItem("senatedistricts",
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(selectInput("senate_districtname", "Select District",
                                         unique(senate$District)),
                             # dateRangeInput("sen_dateRange", "Select Date Range: ",
                             #                format = "mm/yyyy",
                             #                start = min(senate$Date),
                             #                end = max(senate$Date),
                             #                startview = "year",
                             #                separator = " - "),
                             # textOutput("senateDates"),
                             #more stuff here
                             plotly::plotlyOutput("senplot")
                    ))
          ),
          tabItem("assemblydistricts", 
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(selectInput("assembly_districtname", "Select District",  # Set up the tab 
                                         unique(assembly$District)),
                             # dateRangeInput("ad_dateRange", "Select Date Range: ",
                             #                format = "mm/yyyy",
                             #                start = min(senate$Date),
                             #                end = max(senate$Date),
                             #                startview = "year", 
                             #                separator = " - "),
                             # textOutput("assemblyDates"),
                             plotly::plotlyOutput("adplot")
                    ))
          ), 
          tabItem("agegroups",
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(selectInput("agegroup_districtname", "Select Age Group",
                                         unique(ageparty$District)),
                             ##date range goes here
                             plotly::plotlyOutput("ageplot")
                    ))
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
    
    
    
    ###  Assembly the UI -----------------------------------------------------------
    ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                        header = dashboardHeader( title = "Nevada Voter Reg Trends"),
                        sidebar = sidebar,
                        body = body
    )#dashboardBody()
    
    
    
    ### Build the Server -----------------------------------------------------------
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
       CNTY <- reactive({
        county %>%
          filter(District == input$county_districtname, Date == input$county_dateRange)%>%
          select(-District)
           
      })
      
      SEN <- reactive({
        senate %>%
          filter(District == input$senate_districtname)%>%
          select(-District)
      })
      
      AD <- reactive({
        assembly %>%
          filter(District == input$assembly_districtname)%>%
          select(-District)
        
      })
      AGE <- reactive({
        ageparty %>%
          filter(District == input$agegroup_districtname)%>%
          select(-District)
      })
      
      output$assemblyDates <- renderText({Dates$SelectedDates})
      
      Dates <- reactive()
      observe({
        Dates$SelectedDates <- c(as.character(format(input$county_dateRange[1],format = "%m/%Y"))
                                 ,as.character(format(input$county_dateRange[2],format = "%m/%Y")))
      })
      
      ### Plotly outputs--------------------------------------------------------------
      #County
      
      output$countyplot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        
        
        ggplot(CNTY(), aes(x = Date, y = Voters, color = Party, group = Party,
                           label = Percent)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.125) +
          geom_point(size = 2.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen", "blue", "red", "orange","darkgray"),
                             name = "Party") +
          labs(x="Dates", y="Voter Registration", title= paste( input$county_districtname,
                                                                "Voter Registration Trends"),
               caption = "Data Source: Nevada Secretary of State") +
          theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0),
            plot.caption = element_text(hjust = -1)
          )
      })
      #Senate
      output$senplot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        ggplot(SEN(), aes(x = Date, y = Voters, color = Party, group = Party,
                          label = Percent)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.125) +
          geom_point(size = 2.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen", "blue", "red", "orange","darkgray"),
                             name = "Party") +
          labs(x="Dates", y="Voter Registration", title= paste( input$senate_districtname,
                                                                "Voter Registration Trends"),
               caption =  "Data Sourc: Nevada Secretary of State") +
          theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0)
          )
      })
      #AD
      output$adplot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        ggplot(AD(), aes(x = Date, y = Voters, color = Party, group = Party,
                         label = Percent)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.125) +
          geom_point(size = 2.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen", "blue", "red", "orange","darkgray"),
                             name = "Party") +
          labs(x="Dates", y="Voter Registration", title= paste( input$agegroup_districtname,
                                                                "Voter Registration Trends"),
               caption = "Data Source: Nevada Secretary of State") +
          theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0)
          )
      })
      #Age
      output$ageplot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        ggplot(AGE(), aes(x = Date, y = Voters, color = Party, group = Party,
                          label = Percent)) +
          geom_line(size = 1.125) +
          geom_point(size = 2.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen", "blue", "red", "orange","darkgray"),
                             name = "Party") +
          labs(x="Dates", y="Voter Registration", title= paste( input$agegroup_districtname,
                                                                "Voter Registration Trends"),
               caption = "Data Source: Nevada Secretary of State") +
          theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0)
          )
      })
    }
    
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input$count_dateRange` is a vector of length 2. Below it looks like you're treating it as a scalar.

```
  county %>%
      filter(District == input$county_districtname, Date == input$county_dateRange)%>%
      select(-District)
```

Comment: so you need something like `filter(Date >= input$count_dateRange[1], Date <= input$count_dateRange[2] )`

Comment: CNTY <- reactive({
    county %>%
      filter(District == input$county_districtname) %>% 
      filter(Date >= input$count_dateRange[1], Date <= input$count_dateRange[2]) %>%
      select(-District)
  })

This gave me an error in the app. Error in : Result must have length 380, not 0